# Повтор запросов

Tags: sqlite3

Всем привет.

Есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'Players' (map TEXT, name TEXT DEFAULT 'None', time TEXT DEFAULT 'None', runtime float NOT NULL DEFAULT 999999.0, id TEXT DEFAULT '0000');
```

И так. Мне нужно взять количество `map` и с каждым названием из этого параметра сделать запрос:

```
SELECT id FROM 'Players' WHERE map ='%s' AND runtime < 9999 ORDER BY runtime LIMIT 0, 10
```

Я могу это сделать программно. Но тогда у меня получается куча запросов.
Можно ли это сделать в один запрос?

Если я делаю запрос:

```
SELECT id FROM 'Players' WHERE map =(SELECT map FROM 'Players' GROUP BY map) AND runtime < 9999 ORDER BY runtime LIMIT 0, 10
```

То у меня результат только одной строки `map`

Comment: Нельзя так?

Answer (score 1):

вместо

```
map =(SELECT map FROM 'Players' GROUP BY map)
```

напиши

```
map IN (SELECT map FROM 'Players' GROUP BY map)
```

Comment: Ризницы не заметил. Все те же 10 результатов.

Наверное меня не поняли..
Нужно чтобы было по 10 результатов на каждой 'map'